# Is it possible to call moodle API outside of moodle source?

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle version 3.2 . I have to use moodle API in C# . Is it possible to trigger the API? . Please suggest your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use web services for this.

The best starting point for this is: https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Web_services

That page has links off to more detailed documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check on webservice.